# last item selected while clicking previous item in bootstrap scrollspy

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I have tried to implement navigation bar using bootstrap scrollspy and facing issue while clicking on last before item.

Sample:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G82SSF1PNOIG

Step to reproduce:

1. Click the above link and run the sample
2. Click on "My information 2" from the right side navigation section.Now page Will scrolled and child items opened
3. Click on  "Title 1-2" under "My information 2"

You can notice, "My information 3" item was selected instead of selected one.

Comment: Any suggestions in this